Start Node.js with PM2 on Boot
The whole thing should only take 2 minutes, but of course it doesn't work for me.
I tried several versions of PM2 and ran it as root.
There were only success messages, but the corresponding service remained on failed and did not start with the system.
This is the message after pm2 startup
[PM2] Init System found: systemd
Platform systemd
Template
[Unit]
Description=PM2 process manager
Documentation=https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=send
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
Environment=PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/l                                                        ocal/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/u                                                        sr/bin
Environment=PM2_HOME=/root/.pm2
PIDFile=/root/.pm2/pm2.pid
Restart=on-failure

ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect
ExecReload=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 reload all
ExecStop=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Target path
/etc/systemd/system/pm2-send.service
Command list
[ 'systemctl enable pm2-send' ]
[PM2] Writing init configuration in /etc/systemd/system/pm2-send.service
[PM2] Making script booting at startup...
[PM2] [-] Executing: systemctl enable pm2-send...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pm2-send.service → /etc/system                                                        d/system/pm2-send.service.
[PM2] [v] Command successfully executed.
+---------------------------------------+
[PM2] Freeze a process list on reboot via:
$ pm2 save

[PM2] Remove init script via:
$ pm2 unstartup systemd

This is the status of the service
× pm2-send.service - PM2 process manager
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pm2-send.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-06-09 11:32:40 CEST; 13s ago
       Docs: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
    Process: 1448 ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

Jun 09 11:32:40 send systemd[1]: pm2-send.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 09 11:32:40 send systemd[1]: Stopped pm2-send.service - PM2 process manager.
Jun 09 11:32:40 send systemd[1]: pm2-send.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 09 11:32:40 send systemd[1]: pm2-send.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 09 11:32:40 send systemd[1]: Failed to start pm2-send.service - PM2 process manager.

I followed these instructions https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/
my system is debian and the node.js version 16.x
I tried using my own init, systemd and crontab to alternatively start PM2 when booting the system.
None of this worked either
This is my own systemd Code:
Failed with error 203
[Unit]
Description=PM2 Send Service
After=network.target
 
[Service]
ExecStart=pm2 start /etc/send/server/bin/prod.js
ExecReload=pm2 reload all
Type=exec
Restart=always
 
 
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

I tried on the file:
chmod 755
chmod +x

the absolute path is /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2 but this gives the error code 127, I can't call it via the shell either “directory not found”. via ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2 it works via the shell but the service gives “Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path"
systemctl status start-pm2-send.service on my own service gives me:
× start-pm2-send.service - PM2 Send Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/start-pm2-send.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-06-02 16:39:53 CEST; 12s ago
    Process: 1682 ExecStart=pm2 start /etc/send/server/bin/prod.js (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 1682 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms
 
Jun 02 16:39:53 send systemd[1]: start-pm2-send.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 02 16:39:53 send systemd[1]: Stopped start-pm2-send.service - PM2 Send Service.
Jun 02 16:39:53 send systemd[1]: start-pm2-send.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 02 16:39:53 send systemd[1]: start-pm2-send.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 02 16:39:53 send systemd[1]: Failed to start start-pm2-send.service - PM2 Send Service.

i don't know which logs you need or information about the service, please just write to me about it

Does your process start and work if you just use pm2 without trying to start it on boot?

yes without problems . fortunately linux servers do not reboot as often as windows ^^ so i'm always there manually to start pm2 -> but that's no solution.
my service always goes down until i realize it

And if you try to start it with using a bootscript, do you then see a pm2 master process running? But you process does not run?

What exactly do you mean with bootscript?

can you give me an example?

What II meant is: what happens if you try to use init, systemd, ... to start pm2 when booting the system? Does pm2 then run? But just not your process?

This is my systemd Code: https://pastebin.com/27pr23x4
Failed with error 203

neither pm2 nor my servcie start on boot

"Remained on failed" - check what the actual log says and check why it failed (sudo systemctl -u pm2, assuming you called the file pm2.service). My money is on the fact that you forgot to specify the full path to pm2 (should probably be something like /usr/local/bin/pm2 start and not just pm2 start). Also, did you try using the built-in function for registering pm2 as a service (pm2 startup)? See also https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

sudo systemctl -u pm2 The command gives me Invalid option -- u (yes I used it with a single dash). there is no pm2 under /usr/local/bin/, the find command did not find “pm2” on the whole server. yes, I have already tried this several times, as described in my post above

systemctl status start-pm2-send.service gives me: https://pastebin.com/LDKkaM2F

@CherryDT
the absolute path is /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2
but this gives the error code 127, I can't call it via the shell either “directory not found”.
via ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2 it works via the shell but the service gives “Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path”

Sorry, I meant journalctl and not systemctl. In your case that's sudo journalctl -u start-pm2-send. But from your previous message it's already clear that I was right and the missing full path is the problem. Given the error you encountered, are you sure your home directory is indeed /root and not maybe something like /home/ubuntu? So the path would be something like /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/pm2. Use which pm2 in your shell to figure that out. (You might also need ProtectHome=false in your service file then.)

But at that point I really wonder, why did you not use the pm2 startup command I mentioned, which does all that heavy lifting for you?

i tried, I wrote in my post I wish it was that simple.
I tried several versions of PM2 and ran it as root. There were only success messages, but the corresponding service remained on failed and did not start with the system.

which pm2 also gives me /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/pm2
I installed it globally

with the help of a friend we were able to write our own systemd service that works
[Unit]
Description=Furrysend
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node /etc/send/server/bin/prod.js
WorkingDirectory=/etc/send/server/bin
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


On linux, just type the command pm2 startup in a shell to install a startup script.
After that start your process with pm2 start .... Once process started type the command pm2 save to save your actual process configuration.
If you modify your process, once done, issue pm2 save to refresh the startup configuration.
To be complete, if you need to rollback after a process update and if you have  previously issue pm2 save, yous can issue pm2 resurrect to reload last saved configuration.

I have already written in my post that it does not work.
I have now added the output of pm2 startup above
it seems the path to /root/ is the problem

Have you issued commands with sudo ? It seem's that you have run the pm2 command with the user `send'?

no i have switched to root with su.
then I do not use sudo

It's strange, because this line User=send seem's to indicate that the pm2 startup command was executed with a user called send

yes i noticed that too, but i switched from send to root with su

Have you use su or su root command? or su - root command? Can you retry with su - root command or by login directly with root user?

If you haven't use the su - command (with minus) you have not replace most environment variables. So if 'pm2 startup' (don't know exactly how it works internally) rely on environment variables you have execute it with root user, but sith send environment vars.

logging in directly with root is blocked for security reasons. i didn't know that it makes a difference to use su -. thanks for the tip. but we have now found another solution. thanks anyway for your efforts and your time
